# What does [].$ mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

There is a function in JavaScript which calculates the sum of some digits, however I don't understand what this part (`[].$`) means:

```
const sum = d => d != [].$ ? `${d = [...`${d}`].join` + `} = ${eval(d)}` : ``

[].$
```

`[].$` - what is it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> `[].$` - what is it?

It's an empty array literal (`[]`) followed by a property accessor expression (`.$`) looking up the property called `$`.

Since arrays don't normally have a property with that name, presumably it's been set there (or *potentially* set there, given the check) by some previous code. If no code sets it, then it's a short way to write `undefined` (since `[].$` is `undefined` when `$` isn't a property of arrays).

Comment: I think it's there to just have a shorter code for the value `undefined`, since as you said, arrays don't normally have that property

Answer (score 5):

For this particular code, it doesn't have any significant meaning. It's there just to represent the value `undefined` with the least amount of characters. It could equally be `[]._` or just `undefined`.

For how it's interpreted. @T.J.Crowder [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62376370/1656749) summarised it pretty well

Comment: Thank you, your answer is exact that I have asked for. I will mark @T.J.Crowder answer as he summarised these literals. I have marked a plus for your answer. Appreciate your support!

Comment: FWIW, I wouldn't say it has no significant meaning. It means `undefined`, which appears to be significant to its processing. :-) Nevertheless, good point. I haven't seen `[].$` for this purpose before, but it's the shortest I've come across (though creating and throwing away an array seems an odd choice vs. [say] just declaring your own `u` constant).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder There is just one disadvantage of such approach - a simplicity of code's understanding and maintainig for other developers. It is really looks very beatiful but needs some time to catch a sense of it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in that sense it is indeed significant : ) I actually meant it could be easily replaced by something else that has the value `undefined`, not sure how to put it in better words. Also declaring a `u` constant would makes the code just longer.

Comment: @esff - Oh, absolutely. I would never use it. Leave minifying to minifiers.

Comment: @esff FYI there are some situations where readability or performance is not as important as the length of the code ,see [Code Golf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_golf)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Exactly! :)

Comment: @thammada Yeah, you are right. Looks like every project needs special approach. Once again thank you for a clearence of your answer!